React: button not working when extracting to functional component (Chakra-UI IconButton)
Edit: the problem has been solved thanks to Nikita's comment below, but since it's not an answer, I can't mark it as a solution. I can mark my own answer as solution, but I have to wait 2 days.
In the return function of the full React .jsx file at the bottom of this post, I use an IconButton from Chakra-UI. It does exactly what it is supposed to do when I click it: It calls the functions deleteBooking() and fetchBookings(), which, respectively, send a DELETE request to the backend, and refreshes the page. Then the booking is gone. Great.
The problem came when I tried to extract the IconButton into a separate functional component: DeleteBookingButton. I literally just copy and pasted the IconButton into DeleteBookingButton, and return it. So the bottom line of the following code fragment is supposed to display the same button as the lines above it:
<IconButton
  variant='ghost'
  colorScheme='red'
  aria-label='Delete booking'
  fontSize='24px'
  size='sm'
  icon={<MdDelete />}
  onClick={() => {
    deleteBooking(booking.id);
    fetchBookings();
  }}
/>
<DeleteBookingButton id={booking.id} />

However, while the button does show twice, the second version (DeleteBookingButton) doesn't do anything when clicked. Even the alert I put in onClick, doesn't pop up when clicked. The question is: Why doesn't DeleteBookingButton do anything, ?
Illustration: the buttons in the green circle/oval are repsonsive (raw IconButtons), but the buttons in the orange oval don't do anything (DeleteBookingButton).
I use React Vite v5.2.6.
Full .jsx code (except imports) for the relevant route
function BookingOverview() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const token = auth.user?.access_token;
  const [bookingData, setBookingData] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch JSON data
    console.log("useEffect");
    fetchBookings();
  }, [bookingData]);
  
  function fetchBookings() {
    fetch(`${Env.API_BASE_URL}/bookingsNotSecured`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setBookingData([...data._embedded.bookingList]);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }
  
  function deleteBooking(bookingId) {
    fetch(`${Env.API_BASE_URL}/bookings/${bookingId}`, {
      method: 'Delete',
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      })
    })
      .then(response => alert("Status after trying to delete booking with id " + bookingId + ": " + response.status))
      .catch(error => console.error("Error deleting booking " + bookingId + ", status: " + error.status))
  }
  
  function DeleteBookingButton( { id } ) {
    return (
      <IconButton
        variant='ghost'
        colorScheme='red'
        aria-label='Delete booking'
        fontSize='24px'
        size='sm'
        icon={<MdDelete/>}
        onClick={() => {
          alert("Trying to delete booking with id " + id);
          deleteBooking(id);
          fetchBookings();
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <Heading>All Bookings</Heading>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table>
          <Thead>
            <Tr>
              <Th>Id</Th>
              <Th>Room</Th>
              <Th>Start</Th>
              <Th>End</Th>
              <Th>Name</Th>
              <Th>Actions</Th>
            </Tr>
          </Thead>
          <Tbody>
            
            {
              bookingData && bookingData.map(booking => (
                <Tr>
                  <Td>{booking.id}</Td>
                  <Td>{booking.roomId ? booking.roomId : "(none)"}</Td>
                  <Td>{booking.firstDay}</Td>
                  <Td>{booking.lastDay}</Td>
                  <Td>{booking.name}</Td>
                  <Td>
                    <IconButton
                      variant='ghost'
                      colorScheme='red'
                      aria-label='Delete booking'
                      fontSize='24px'
                      size='sm'
                      icon={<MdDelete />}
                      onClick={() => {
                        deleteBooking(booking.id);
                        fetchBookings();
                      }}
                    />
                    <DeleteBookingButton id={booking.id} />
                  </Td>
                </Tr>
              ))
            }
          </Tbody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
}

export default BookingOverview;

Btw, it does not have to do with the parameter {id}, because even if I just replace id with 1, it doesn't delete booking 1, even though it's the correct url to do so.

First of all, useEffect is dependent on bookingData, which it updates internally. You get recursion as a result.

Thank you, removing the recursion somehow fixed the problem

Thanks to @Nikita-Skrebets for pointing out an obvious problem that I somehow overlooked.
Removing the recursion (by using a flag variable just to trigger useEffect), and besides that removing the duplicate call to fetchBookings, somehow fixed my issue.
You would think that would make it so that both buttons didn't work before, but only the one in the separate function had a problem. Both work now!
